# Hide IP address in source with Website Masking?

Tags: hosting, ip, masking, domain-masking

I am a bit of a novice on web hosting - We have built a site in Flex that is delivered on a SaaS basis. We have put a dedicated system for a client on a URL of their choosing (purchased through Go-Daddy) and have put a simple forward with Masking on the site. This works fine but in the view source on the browser, it shows the IP address which is obviously a security issue. I have tried changing the IP in the DNS to the IP the site is located at on our server but as we use a sub-IP (i.e. 10.10.100.100:1000), it won't accept it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is showing the IP address of a web server a security concern? Web servers are meant to be public, and anyone who knows what they're doing can find the IP by looking at the DNS anyway. The user may not need to know, but their computer does, otherwise they couldn't request content from the server.

Comment: Also, by "sub-IP", do you mean the :1000 at the end? If so, that's a port, not different IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to install a reverse proxy. My understanding of  your case is that there's a browser A using your clients site B which either pulls in resources or accesses in some other way from server C. Ypu want to hide all references to server C, so that it looks like B is stand-alone. configure your web server on B to act as a reverse proxy to C for a specific set of resources.